# App crashing when switching activities with crash report

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

When I switch between two of my activities it works fine they switch with no problem. But after switching a few times it doesn't work and the app crashes.Even after I close and open the application it still doesn't work. What is wrong with my application.Here is the Main activity file:

```
 package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

 import static com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon.R.id.textView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageButton myButton;
private int Counter;
private ImageButton autoclick;
private TextView myTextView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int add;
private TextView myAddView;
private ImageButton singleclick;
private int Singleadd = 1;
private ImageButton money;
private boolean[] array;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Counter = readCountFromFile();
    add = readAddFromFile();
    Singleadd=readSingleFromFile();
    if(Singleadd==0){
        Singleadd=1;
    }

    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("Count")) {
            Counter = bundle.getInt("Count");
        }
        if (bundle.containsKey("Add")) {
            add = bundle.getInt("Add");
        }
        if (bundle.containsKey("Single")) {
            Singleadd = bundle.getInt("Single");
        }

    }


    money = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    autoclick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.autoclick);
    singleclick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.singleclick);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(textView);
    myAddView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Counter = ButtonCounter(Counter);
        }
    });
    autoclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
            intent.putExtra("Add", add);
            intent.putExtra("Single", Singleadd);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    singleclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
            intent.putExtra("Single", Singleadd);
            intent.putExtra("Add", add);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    writeCounttofile();
    writeAddtofile();
    writeSingletofile();
}


public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Counter = AutoCounter(Counter, add);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display(Counter, add);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    }, 50);
}


public int ButtonCounter(int Counter) {
    Counter += Singleadd;
    return Counter;
}

public int AutoCounter(int Counter, int add) {
    Counter = Counter + add;
    return Counter;
}

public void Display(int Counter, int add) {
    String money = String.valueOf(Counter);
    myTextView.setText(":" + money);
    myAddView.setText("$" + add + "/Per Second");

}

public void writeCounttofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("countvalue.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(String.valueOf(Counter));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}


private int readCountFromFile() {

    String result = "";
    int countervalue = 0;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("countvalue.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String tempString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(tempString);

            }

            inputStream.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            countervalue = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return countervalue;
}

public void writeAddtofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("addvalue.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(String.valueOf(add));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}


private int readAddFromFile() {

    String result = "";
    int add = 0;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("addvalue.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String tempString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(tempString);

            }

            inputStream.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            add = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return add;
}

public void writeSingletofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("singlevalue.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(String.valueOf(singleclick));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}


private  int readSingleFromFile() {

    String result = "";
    int single = 1;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("singlevalue.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String tempString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(tempString);

            }

            inputStream.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            single = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return single;
}


 }
```

Crash Log:

```
08-17 23:57:07.124 21715-21715/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-17 23:57:07.226 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon       
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:/data/app/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon-1/lib/arm64
08-17 23:57:07.236 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-17 23:57:07.287 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-17 23:57:07.308 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
08-17 23:57:07.308 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon V/BoostFramework: mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
08-17 23:57:07.308 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon V/BoostFramework: mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
08-17 23:57:07.308 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
08-17 23:57:07.308 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon V/BoostFramework: mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
08-17 23:57:07.310 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ca25221
08-17 23:57:07.310 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ca93646
08-17 23:57:07.403 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-17 23:57:07.404 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
                                                                               Process: com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon, PID: 21715         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android.widget.ImageButton{8f1bae8 VFED..C.. ......ID 97,1733-209,1845 #7f0d0081 app:id/singleclick}"
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android.widget.ImageButton{8f1bae8 VFED..C.. ......ID 97,1733-209,1845 #7f0d0081 app:id/singleclick}"
                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                                                                                    at com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon.MainActivity.readSingleFromFile(MainActivity.java:282)
                                                                                    at com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
 08-17 23:57:07.404 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
 08-17 23:57:07.412 21715-21715/com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21715 SIG: 9
```

Please & Thank You.

Comment: Can you please split your activities into two separate code block

Comment: exception is self explanatory **string "android.widget.ImageButton{8f1bae8 VFED..C.. ......ID 97,1733-209,1845 #7f0d0081 app:id/singleclick}" is not an integer** did you at least read an exception?

Comment: Show your singlevalue.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your error is in MainActivity  inside readCountFromFile() method.

The problem is here

```
        result = stringBuilder.toString();
        single = Integer.parseInt(result);
```

Since result can be empty or something

```
Integer.parseInt(result);
```

can cause NumberFormatException

So just try to catch it

```
private  int readSingleFromFile() {

String result = "";
int single = 1;
try {

    InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("singlevalue.txt");

    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String tempString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(tempString);
        }

        inputStream.close();

        result = stringBuilder.toString();
        single = Integer.parseInt(result);

    }


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NumberFormatException() {
  //here you catch and watch the problem
  Log.e("MyActivity", "cant parse string: "+result); 
}
return single;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this log

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: 
 "android.widget.ImageButton{8f1bae8 VFED..C.. ......ID 97,1733-
 209,1845 #7f0d0081 app:id/singleclick}"
```

I think you have a problem with `writeSingleToFile()` and `readSingleFromFile()`.

In `writeSingleToFile` you are calling `String.valueof(singleclick)`. This will end up calling the `toString()` method of the `ImageButton` class. Then, in `readSingleFromFile()` you are trying to parse this value to an int, which is failing.

I think you need to revise your logic and double check what you are trying to save.

Answer (score 0):

You believe that value you read from file is always an integer

```
single = Integer.parseInt(result);
```

But it's not. Hence it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "android.widget.ImageButton{8f1bae8 VFED..C.. ......ID 97,1733-209,1845 #7f0d0081 app:id/singleclick}"
```

Look, it tries to convert this String to int:

> android.widget.ImageButton{8f1bae8 VFED..C.. ......ID 97,1733-209,1845 #7f0d0081 app:id/singleclick}

You need to check your logic and write to the file the value you intended.
Anyway, when you read something from "remote" storage you need to check if it is eligible for you. Also, you need to develop your logic such way that it would work even the value your read from the file is unexpected.

You may try to wrap **Integer.parseInt(result);** in try/catch and properly process an exception in catch section, for example, you may return some default value that is ok for your logic.